# Create Zip file from bytes files Flutter web

Tags: flutter, web, get, zip, firebase-storage

I use firebase cloud storage to store some files, then, i have to put them in a zip file and download it, i have to do this **ONLY** on web, and thats the hard part.
im doing it like this now:

```
FloatingActionButton(
    child: const Icon(Icons.download),
    onPressed: () async {
      List<int>? bytes;
      webarc.ZipEncoder encoder = webarc.ZipEncoder();
      webarc.Archive archive = webarc.Archive();

      try {
        List<String> links = await Database.formLinks();

        for (String link in links) {
          String fileName = link.substring(link.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
          http.Response response = await http.get(
            Uri.parse(link),
            headers: headers,
          );
          webarc.ArchiveFile file = webarc.ArchiveFile.stream(
            fileName,
            response.bodyBytes.elementSizeInBytes,
            response.bodyBytes.toList(),
          );
          archive.addFile(file);
        }
        webarc.OutputStream outputStream = webarc.OutputStream(
          byteOrder: webarc.LITTLE_ENDIAN,
        );
        bytes = encoder.encode(
          archive,
          level: webarc.Deflate.BEST_COMPRESSION,
          modified: DateTime.now(),
          output: outputStream,
        );
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: 'Errore nel download dello zip.',
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
          gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
        );
        return;
      }
      if (bytes == null) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: 'Errore nel download dello zip. bytes nulli.',
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
          gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
        );
        return;
      }

      String zipFileName = 'forms.zip';

      await FileSaver.instance.saveFile(
        zipFileName,
        Uint8List.fromList(bytes),
        'zip',
        mimeType: MimeType.ZIP,
      );

      Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: 'Zip downloadato correttamente.',
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
      );
    },
  ),
```

its all perfect, except for the fact that i download the zip file, but the zip file is empty.

I tryied doing this in many different ways, downloading it with html package, anchoring and clicking a div, but now i think that the package doesnt work, how can i do this? Any help will be accepted, thanks.

P.S.
Here is the database.formLinks function:

```
 static Future<List<Reference>> getCompiledForms() async =>
  (await formsRef.listAll()).items;

 static Future<List<String>> formLinks() async {
final List<Reference> forms = await getCompiledForms();
final List<String> links = [];
for (final form in forms) {
  String url = await form.getDownloadURL();
  links.add(url);
}
return links;
```

}
And those are the packages that i've used in those functions:

archive: ^3.1.2 (As webarc)

http: ^0.13.3 (as http)

file_saver: ^0.0.10

fluttertoast: ^8.0.7

cloud_firestore: ^2.3.0

Answer (score 7):

I was struck with a similar issue this week and was able to figure out the problem. I am using html download using anchor.click() method.

Download files as zip method takes input as list of file names as String and list of file data as Uint8List.

Try this and let me know if this works for you!

```
  _downloadFilesAsZIP(context, List<String> filenames, files) {
    var encoder = ZipEncoder();
    var archive = Archive();
    ArchiveFile archiveFiles = ArchiveFile.stream(
      filenames[0].toString(),
      files[0].lengthInBytes,
      files[0],
    );
    print(archiveFiles);
    archive.addFile(archiveFiles);
    var outputStream = OutputStream(
      byteOrder: LITTLE_ENDIAN,
    );
    var bytes = encoder.encode(archive,
        level: Deflate.BEST_COMPRESSION, output: outputStream);
    print(bytes);
    downloadFile("out.zip", bytes);
  }

  downloadFile(String fileName, Uint8List bytes) {

    final blob = html.Blob([bytes]);
    final url = html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);
    final anchor = html.document.createElement('a') as html.AnchorElement
      ..href = url
      ..style.display = 'none'
      ..download = fileName;
    html.document.body.children.add(anchor);

// download
    anchor.click();

// cleanup
    html.document.body.children.remove(anchor);
    html.Url.revokeObjectUrl(url);
  }
```

Comment: Hello, in my case I had this error:

The argument type 'Uint8List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'InputStreamBase'.

Inside ArchiveFile.stream

Can you help me?

Comment: Try casting it. Example: value as InputStreamBase

Comment: this way is not working... I had try casting but the same error happen

Comment: Could you please share your code as a new question? It would be easy to answer that way! Thanks

Comment: Hello, I had success with my problem. I uploaded a zip archive with my photo urls and after that I download the zip archive in other screen on my app. Works fine.